# Get specific Value part from value in k2 extra field

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, joomla, joomla-k2

Currently I know how to call for specific value in k2 item, but now I need to know if it is possible to call for specific 'value in value'.

Example I have this value ( multi select ): Value1,Value11,Value111,Value1111.

That I know how to call with this code:

```
<!-- preparing it for a call -->
    <?php  
$extrafields = array();
foreach($this->item->extra_fields as $item)
{    
$extrafields[$item->id] = $item->value;
}   
?>
<!-- caling value -->
<?php echo $extrafields[30];?>
```

So code above will show all values from k2 extra field with ID 30.
In my case it is value1,value11,value111,value1111.

What I need know is option to shown only value1 ?

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Maybe something with arrays I dont really know..

Comment: what is K2? where you are using it

Comment: K2 is joomla component for content...